# Identity_insert is set to OFF error even-though it is set to ON

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, identity-insert

I get an error

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Table1' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

I have set the `IDENTITY_INSERT` to `ON` by using the query `SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Database1].[dbo].[Table1] ON`, but still i get this error. In my case I am trying to copy the data of one table to an another so copying the `ID`. I have set the `identity_insert` to `ON`. I do not know why i get this error.

```
CREATE TABLE [Database1].[dbo].[Table1]
   (ID int IDENTITY,
    Machinetyp nvarchar(255),
    Flaeche float not null,
    Losnumberr nvarchar(255),
    Current float not null,
    RK float not null,
);
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Database1].[dbo].[Table1] ON
```

Comment: As you have shown no code all we can do is guess. My guess is that you execute the statement in a `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ` in a different scope that has exited

Comment: Are you the owner of the table or have ALTER permission on the table? Also, please edit your question to provide your code.

Comment: @Sami Yes i am the owner of the table. Yes i will put my code.

Comment: @user9630935 You need to provide the `INSERT` statement too.

Comment: @sami The insert statement i call it in Groovy.

Comment: Are you trying to permanently leave `IDENTITY_INSERT` turned on on `Table1`? if so, why even use the `IDENTITY` property?

Comment: @user9630935 So you need to `IDENTITY_INSERT ON` in Groovy too, and re-set it to `OFF` when you done.

Comment: @user9630935 `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` is session bound. You can't turn it on in the `CREATE` statement and then `INSERT` from the application and expect it to use the setting from another session.

Comment: But, still sounds like you shouldn't be using `IDENTITY` at all.

Comment: @Larnu I have a column ID in an other table. I wanted to copy into this table1. What do you suggest me doing.

Comment: So `table1` is a temporary object? Will it have more rows inserted into it after you "copy" the data?

Comment: @Larnu Its more like synchronization of one table into another. Yes more rows will be inserted. I have a live database having a table. I wanted a backup database table

Comment: Then, as @Sami said, use `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON` (and `OFF`) in Groovy.

Comment: okie. I will try it out. Thank you both.